# waitpid blocking when it shouldn't

Tags: c, linux, shell, signals, wait

I am writing a mini-shell(no, not for school :P; for my own enjoyment) and most of the basic functionality is now done but I am stuck when trying to handle SIGTSTP.

Supposedly, when a user presses `Ctrl+Z`, SIGTSTP should be sent to the Foreground process of the shell if it exists, and Shell should continue normally.

After creating each process(if it's a Foreground process), the following code waits:

```
if(waitpid(pid, &processReturnStatus, WUNTRACED)>0){//wait stopped too
    if(WIFEXITED(processReturnStatus) || WIFSIGNALED(processReturnStatus))
        removeFromJobList(pid);
}
```

And I am handling the signal as follows:

```
void sigtstpHandler(int signum)
{
    signum++;//Just to remove gcc's warning
    pid_t pid = findForegroundProcessID();
    if(pid > -1){
        kill(-pid, SIGTSTP);//Sending to the whole group
    }
}
```

What happens is that when I press `Ctrl+Z`, the child process does get suspended indeed(using `ps -all` to view the state of the processes) but my shell hangs at `waitpid` it never returns even though I passed `WUNTRACED` flag which as far as I understood is supposed to make `waitpid` return when the process is stopped too.
So what could I have possible done wrong? or did I understand waitpid's behavior incorrectly?

Notes:
-findForegroundProcessID() returns the right pid; I double checked that.
-I am changing each process's group when right after I `fork` 
-Handling `Ctrl+C` is working just fine
-If I use another terminal to send SIGCONT after my shell hangs, the child process resumes its work and the shell reaps it eventually.
-I am catching SIGTSTP which as far as I read(and tested) can be caught.
-I tried using waitid instead of waitpid just in case, problem persisted.
**EDIT:**

```
void sigchldHandler(int signum)
{
    signum++;//Just to remove the warning
    pid_t pid;
    while((pid = waitpid(-1, &processReturnStatus, 0)) > 0){    
        removeFromJobList(pid);
    }
    if(errno != ECHILD)
        unixError("kill error");
}
```

My SIGCHLD handler.

Comment: IIUC, you are trying to catch SIGSTP. You can't catch SIGSTP or SIGKILL.

Comment: I am not sure if SIGSTOP is the same as SIGSTP but according to a book, SIGSTOP can't be caught but SIGTSTP can, in fact I am sure I caught it because I did print something as a test

Comment: Oops, my bad. If I read correctly, SIGTSTP was intentionally created to allow it to be caught, to allow the process-group/terminal-group to propagate it among its members. If the book you refer to is APUE, you will probably be able to do it correctly...

Comment: Your waitpid() call looks ok, so test your other assumptions.  When blocked in waitpid(), what happens if you 'kill -TSTP' the child from another terminal?  What happens if you 'kill -KILL' the child from another terminal?

Comment: @fizzer 'kill -TSTP' hangs the shell, sending kill -CONT again lets it continue working normally(as in, the child resumes and shell keeps waiting).
sending kill -KILL terminates the child, wait returns and shell continues normally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SIGCHLD` is delivered for stopped children.  The `waitpid()` call *in the signal handler* - which doesn't specify `WUNTRACED` - blocks forever.

You should probably not have the `removeFromJobList()` processing in two different places.  If I had to guess, it sounds like it touches global data structures, and doesn't belong in a signal handler.

Comment: I should have read more about SIGCHLD, indeed catching it was what caused the wait to block, it wasn't the wait in the processCreation bu t rather the wait in the signal handler. 

Thanks a lot =)

Answer (score 1):

Waitpid is not returning because you are not not setting a sigchld handler (which I sent you earlier). You have child processess that are not getting reaped. Furthermore, waitpid needs to be in a while loop, not an if (also sent you that).

The only signal you are supposed to catch is SIGCHLD. The reason being is that if your processes are forked properly, the kernel will send that signal to the foreground process and it will terminate it or stop it or do whatever the signal is properly.

When process groups are not set correctly, signals will get sent to the wrong process. One way to test that is by running a foreground process and hitting Ctrl-Z. If your entire shell exists, then Ctrl-Z signal is getting sent to the entire shell. This means you did not set the new process in a new process group and gave it a terminal.

Now here's what you need to do if your Ctrl-Z signal is stopping your entire shell. Once you fork a process, in the child process:
- Set the process in its own group using setpgid.
- Give it a sane terminal by blocking SIGTTOU and then giving it the terminal using tcsetpgrp.

In the parent:
- Also set its child process using setpgid. This is because you have no idea if the child or the parent will execute first, so this avoids a race condition. It doesn't hurt to set it twice.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am setting a sigchld hanlder(hence why handling Ctrl+C works just fine).
This sounds a bit weird, you're saying the only signal I am supposed to handle is SIGCHLD? but I don't get SIGCHLD when a child receives a SIGTSTP signal but I think I might have understood what you mean.

The idea is to make give a new process its own terminal and make it foreground so when Ctrl+Z goes, it hits the foreground process only and not my shell without handling Ctrl+Z altogether?

Comment: I am setting my signal handler, as I have already stated above, and I confirmed now the child process IS receiving the signal and is being stopped but wait is still not returning.